# Pandas- correct way to create a new column based on the sum of rows of another column (value trying to be set on a copy)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with dates, names, and values, and all I want to do is create a column that is the output of the total sum of values by date, then subtract that sum by the value for each name for that date. I've been able to do this, but am getting the common error: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.`

This is my code: `df['ex_Term'] = df.groupby('name').Term.transform('sum') - df['Term']`

It's telling me to use the iloc function and after reading the documentation and trying this code, it still didn't work: `df['ex_Term'] = df.groupby('name').loc[:,('Term')].sum()- df['Term']`

example df:

```
 name   Country   value   delta  
 mike   UK            1      -1  
 mike   US            2       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC try using `assgin`

```
df=df.assgin(ex_Term=df.groupby('name').Term.transform('sum') - df['Term'])
```

Comment: awesome thanks! and if I wanted to groupby multiple values (if I had country and item), would I just do `df.groupby(['name','country'])`?

Comment: @DickThompson yes, that is the way, if you do not want the group key value become index, you can add `df.groupby(['name','country'],as_index=False)`

Comment: okay that makes sense, thanks. so if I wanted to get data by change (so if the indexes are Canada, US, and UK, for the row US I want to get US minus Canada and UK), what would I do? I can't just sum by the column right?

Comment: @DickThompson can you show some sample data? I think that would be easy to address your question

Comment: @DickThompson using `diff`

Comment: diff where? by groupby?

Comment: @DickThompson, df.groupby('name')['something'].diff()

Comment: thanks for the help, but now I'm just getting NaNs. My syntax is: `df = df.assign(delta= df.groupby(['name','country'])['value'].diff())`

Comment: @DickThompson diff will always return NaN for the first place, for example, you have two number , 1,2, but for the different , you can only get 1

Comment: I only have 2 countries- UK and US

Comment: @DickThompson using `df.groupby(['name'])['value'].diff()` in assgin

Comment: @DickThompson `df = df.assign(delta=df.groupby(['name'])['value'].diff())`

Comment: yeah that is exactly what I wrote?

Comment: @DickThompson you are grouping by name and country